# What's the best way to ask quesions that involve multiple disciplines on stack?

Tags: discussion

For instance: I'm designing an outdoor, landscaped space for a client. Deck construction questions go to "Home Improvement", best perennials for the geography go to "Gardening" and how to safely install & waterproof the required lighting *could* be "Home Improvement" or "Electrical Engineering".

My design is very holisitc in that the plant recommendations need to match certain construction considerations and the lighting needs to work with the landscaping and deck. I don't feel I can break out one question without a description of the full project.

I see two options:

"I'm designing this lit and landscaped deck that blah blah blah" gets posted to all three sites, with the site specific question (which treated lumber is best/which landscaping grasses will survive the winter very well/how do I calculate the power I need to install) appended to the end of the question. This could be construed as (and penalized for being) a repeat question across sites.

Alternately, I could choose one site for the detailed desription of the projcet, then post "I'm doing the project descried at [hyperlink] and need to know how to calculate power draw" to the other sites...links that reference the full context of what I'm asking.

Is there a preferred way of doing this?

Comment: None of this belongs on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), in my opinion.